# how to use the math and text font that was used in this Math Journal Crux Mathematicorum in the link?

Tags: fonts

I wish to use the font for math and text as here in this document:

[Crux Mathematicorum](https://cms.math.ca/crux/backfile/Crux_v21n07_Sep.pdf) (direct pdf-Download, 6.5MB)

Could you please show how to set in the preamble?

Comment: `pdffonts` tells me that there is Helvetica, Times New Roman, FreeSerif and Courier used. Best to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX along with `fontspec` to use them in your document.

Comment: There is a purple title page and an article, both using different fonts. The latter seems to be a scan, so `pdffonts` cannot get it. Which fonts are you talking about?

Comment: I mean the fonts in the scanned pages, not the cover which is recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Lucida Bright. I own both the Type1 and OpenType version and I'm able to reproduce the typesetting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}


\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1cm}

\begin{document}

{\Large\bfseries 2064.}
\textit{Proposed by Murray S. Klamkin, University of Alberta}

Show that
\[
3\max\left\{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a},\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{c}\right\}
\geq
(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)
\]
for arbitrary positive real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$.

\end{document}
```

### My output

[image]

### Original PDF

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I tried but the font is not on my computer.

Comment: Commercial; you can buy it at http://lucidafonts.com

Comment: Is it possible to typset Vietnamese with this font?

Comment: @Thumbolt Based on the information at http://lucidafonts.com/fonts/lucida-grande/light/wgl, it doesn't seem that the Lucida fonts provide many characters.

Comment: some of the lucida fonts are available [through tug](http://tug.org/store/lucida/). a tugboat article described the [status of the lucida fonts as of 2011](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101vieth.pdf).  support for vietnamese isn't clear, but doesn't appear to be available at present.

Comment: @Thumbolt Hey! You're right! Lucida Bright is not there!

Comment: Is this set of fonts similar to the ones suggested by Sverre? http://store.pctexstore.com/lucidafonts.html

Comment: @Thumbolt Those are the “classical” Lucida fonts (the version for `pdflatex`), but I'm afraid they don't cover Vietnamese either.